# Boundaries of the triple integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need to calculate the triple integral $\iiint_V y\,dx\,dy\,dz$ where $V$ is deterimned by $y\geq x^2, z\leq 4-y, 0\leq z \leq3$. I get $\int_{-1}^1 dx \int_{x^2}^1 y \, dy \int_0^3 dz + 2\int_1^2 dx \int_1^{x^2} y \, dy \int_0^{4-y}$ and I obtain $\dfrac{248}{35}$, while I should get $\dfrac{1016}{35}$. I suppouse that my borders are wrong since I'm having trouble determining the borders in the Z direction.

Answer (score 0):

In the order given, we obtain

$\displaystyle\int_0^3\int_0^{4-z}\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}y\;dxdydz=\int_0^3\int_0^{4-z}2y^{3/2}\;dydz=\frac{4}{5}\int_0^3(4-z)^{5/2}\;dz=\frac{1016}{35}$.

---

Alternate solutions:

$\displaystyle\int_0^3\int_{-\sqrt{4-z}}^{\sqrt{4-z}}\int_{x^2}^{4-z}y\;dydxdz=\int_0^3\int_{-\sqrt{4-z}}^{\sqrt{4-z}}\frac{1}{2}((4-z)^2-x^4)\;dxdz=\int_0^3\frac{4}{5}(4-z)^{5/2}dz=\frac{1016}{35}$

---

$\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}\int_0^3y\;dzdxdy+\int_1^4\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}\int_0^{4-y}y\;dzdxdy$

$=\displaystyle\int_0^16y^{3/2}\;dy+\int_1^4(8y^{3/2}-2y^{5/2})\;dy=\frac{1016}{35}$.

Comment: What would be the boundaries if you "switched" the order in which you integrate x and y?

Comment: Are you referring to the order $dydxdz$?

Comment: Yes and $dxdydz$.